# Shift key doesn't get released when toggle is activated

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to write a script that holds down the LShift key on a toggle. I'm looking to use it in a game named Path of Exile but it's not working as it should.

Here's my code:

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

*Numpad2::
    Toggle := !Toggle
    
    If Toggle
        SendInput {LShift Down}
    Else
        SendInput {LShift Up}

return
```

The goal is to get the script to hold Shift when I press Numpad2, and for it to release Shift when I press Numpad2 again. What I noticed is that it takes two Numpad2 presses for Shift to be held down, and any subsequent Numpad2 presses do not release the Shift key. Can't figure out what could be causing this and any help would be useful.

I should also mention that changing LShift to LCtrl doesn't bring me the same issue. One press on Numpad2, the Ctrl key is held down and another press will release it just like how it's supposed to.